# Cannot access advanced administration options with NetGear router

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, wireless-router

**Background:**

We live in a rural area, so we have to use a wireless connection to a cell tower. Bell provided us with a NetGear router as part of their setup package. Because of their expensive prices, I found the router's "Traffic Meter" setting to be helpful to monitor *everyone's* bandwidth usage, rather than just my PC's.

**Problem:**

I went to check on the traffic meter today and the option *was gone* from the menu! I only ever administrate the router on my PC using Google Chrome. However, logging into it on my BlackBerry tablet worked correctly, which seemed to imply my PC is the problem here.

This is how it should look (note the "Advanced Setup" option under the "WPS Wizard" tab):

[image: Screenshot]

while this is a screenshot of what my router currently displays.

[image: Screenshot]

**What I have tried:**

- Reboot the PC and router
- Clear internet cookies and cache
- Contact tech support (tried phone, email, and chat support and couldn't get through to anybody)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that one of the filters used by Adblock and Adblock Plus has recently started removing the "Advanced Setup" button from the Netgear genie web page.

One way to fix:

1. Go to the Netgear genie web page.
2. While on that page, left-click the Adblock icon in your browser, located to the right of the address bar.
3. Then left click the option to "Don't run on this page" from the drop-down list.

The page will then reload and you should now see the Advanced Setup button.

More discussion can be found here:

https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27959

Comment: Oh my gosh, it's always something so simple! Thank you!